# PostgreSQL database on EC2: Connection refused

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my Django app and PostgreSQL database set up on two EC2 instances in the same VPC. App is on the instance with subnet connected to internet gateway; database is on instance with subnet that has no internet gateway.

The app instance's private IP is 10.0.0.164; the database instance's private IP is 10.0.1.136.

When I try to connect my Django app to the database, I get the error

> could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running
>   on host "10.0.1.136" and accepting    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

However, I have allowed inbound TCP traffic on port 5432 on the database instance. My security group rules for the instance that hosts the database:

Inbound: allow all TCP and ICMP IPV4&IPV6 traffic in all ports from the internal IP address of the instance hosting the Django app (10.0.0.164/32)

(screenshot of my inbound rules https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ukjJ.jpg)

Outbound: allow all traffic in all ports to anywhere

My `pg_hba.conf` file on the database EC2 instance:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             10.0.0.164/32           trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   articles        postgres                                md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

My `postgresql.conf` file has set listening address to '10.0.0.164, 127.0.0.1' and port to '5432'.

My database settings in Django's `settings.py`:

```
ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'articles',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': '10.0.1.136',
            'PORT': '5432',
```

What else can I do to make the database instance accept connection?

EDIT: My EC2 instances are running Ubuntu 16.04

EDIT: this is what I got from running `sudo lsof -nP -i | grep LISTEN` on the database instance: `postgres 1823 postgres    6u  IPv4  19766      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)`

I ran `sudo ufw allow 5432` and still same error

When I ran `netstat -nlt` on the database instance, I don't see port 5432

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? Make sure you allow the port  5432 on the Operating System Firewall. For example in Ubuntu you have to do ```sudo ufw allow 5432```.

Comment: @Pedro Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for reminding me to include that info! I will try that command

Comment: @Pedro Do you mean I have to do `sudo ufw allow 5432` on the database instance or the app instance?

Comment: Just to be clear your database is an EC2 instance right? not RDS

Comment: @Pedro yes EC2, not RDS

Comment: @Pedro I did `sudo ufw allow 5432` on both instances and still get the same error =(

Comment: The Ubuntu Firewall (ufw) blocks incoming connections, so you have to run the command in the database instance.

Comment: @Pedro I just did and restarted everything and still get the same error =(

Comment: have you tried pinging the database server from the app instance?

Comment: @Pedro good point! I just nmap-ed the server's port 5432 and it returned that the port is closed. I already ran sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp and sudo ufw allow 5432 on the instance. why is it still closed?

Comment: Try disabling the firewall (database instance) ```sudo ufw disable``` and pinging again. You can check the status of the firewall using ```sudo ufw status```

Comment: @Pedro just did. still says closed when I nmap from the app instance

Comment: @Pedro I just solved the issue! will post answer. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I have the same setup (I am noob with networking) and I can't understand how you edit the ```postgresql.conf``` which is sitting in the private subnet. Do you ssh into the public ec2 and then another ssh into the db instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
postgres 1823 postgres    6u  IPv4  19766      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
```

That's your issue right there, your postgres is bound to localhost only.

Change the IP that postgres is listening on by editing the `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` or `/etc/postgresql/"Version number here"/main/postgresql.conf` file and change the listen address as follows...

```
listen_addresses='127.0.0.1 10.0.1.136'
```

you must state listening addresses as I have without the commas in later versions of postgres

I hope this resolves your issue! :)

Comment: yup that was the issue! thanks! just posted an answer that detailed how I resolved the issue

Comment: Glad I could help, I also noticed that you said the listening address was 10.0.1.164 in your question, I'm assuming that's the address of the Django app and not the database? That would probably be the reason why it was only listening on localhost :)

Comment: same problem occured to me. but I cannot find postgresql.conf file. in windows how can i find that file?

Answer (score 2):

This page solved my issue: https://zaiste.net/postgresql_allow_remote_connections/

I ran `sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres` and found that my Postgres is actually running on port 1823 (WHY). I edited my `postgresql.conf` to allow all `listen_addresses` (`listen_addresses = '*'`) then changed my Django database settings to port 1823

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that your DB is in EC2 instance, check the inbound rules of the instance. Saw the image of inbound rules. Source should be 0.0.0.0/0,::/0 instead on the instance ip